# Faster way to count values by a "kind" and update value in the DataFrame with that count?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I am trying to implement a step in a script where I look up, in each row, the "kind" of a value, which is stored in the same DataFrame, and update a count per row of how many values are of each "kind". To illustrate, here is a toy example:

```py
d = {0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 1: [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
 2: [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
 3: [2, 1, 8, 3, 6, 5, 10, 3, 4, 7],
 4: [0, 0, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 9],
 5: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 6: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.index += 1
```

In `df`, `df[0]` contains a unique ID of an object, `df[1]`, contains the "kind" (this could be like a color of the object). `df[3]` and `df[4]` contain adjacent objects of interest (0 is a placeholder value, and any nonzero value is the ID of an adjacent object, so here we either have 1 or 2 adjacent objects). `df[5]` and `df[6]` are for storing how many objects are of each type. Here there are just two types, which are ints, so counts for adjacent objects of type 1 go in `df[5]` and adjacent objects of type 2 go in `df[6]`.

I have working code that iterates over the rows and adjacent object columns, and looks up the type, then increments the appropriate column. However, this does not scale well, and my actual datasets have many more rows and object types, and this operation is called repeatedly as part of a Monte-Carlo type simulation. I'm not exactly sure what could be done here to speed it up, I've tried just a dictionary lookup of ID:Type, but that was actually slower. Here is the functional code:

```py
def countNeighbors(contactMap): #in case of subgraph, still need to know the neighbors type
    for index, row in contactMap.iterrows():
        for col in range(3,4):
            cellID = row[col]
            if cellID == 0:
                pass
            else:
                cellType = int(contactMap[contactMap[0] == cellID][1])
                contactMap.at[index, 4+cellType] += 1
    return contactMap

df = countNeighbors(df)
```

Expected output:

```py
output = {0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 1: [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2], 2: [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 3: [2, 1, 8, 3, 6, 5, 10, 3, 4, 7], 4: [0, 0, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 9], 5: [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 6: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]}

out_df = pd.DataFrame(output)
out_ df.index += 1
```

So to be clear, this output means that object 1 (row 1), is of type 1, with 1 adjacent object, Object 2. We look up Object 2 in `df` and see that it is of type 1, and so increment col 5. 
Is there a faster way to accomplish the same effect? I'm open to redesigning the data structure if required, but this format is convenient.

Comment: I think this might be the only case I've seen where an example is a bit too vague. It would also help if you display what you would want your output to look like.

Comment: What is `df[2]`?

Comment: @BenPap the final line with that function returns the desired output, but I will update momentarily with an explicit illustration.

Comment: Your expected output seems to be incorrect at index 3, 4, 9, and 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1:

```
type_dict = df.set_index(0)[1].to_dict()

for i in [3,4]:
    s = df[i].map(type_dict)
    df.loc[:,[5,6]] += pd.get_dummies(s)[[1,2]].values
```

## Option 2:

```
df.loc[:,[5,6]] = (pd.get_dummies(df[[3,4]]
                     .stack().map(type_dict))
                     .sum(level=0)
                  )
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   1   1   1   2   0   1   0
2   2   1   1   1   0   1   0
3   3   2   2   8   4   1   1
4   4   2   2   3   9   1   1
5   5   1   1   6   0   1   0
6   6   1   1   5   0   1   0
7   7   2   1   10  0   0   1
8   8   1   1   3   0   0   1
9   9   1   2   4   10  0   2
10  10  2   2   7   9   1   1
```